# Make Image Drop Shadow

Tags: android, android-imageview, dropshadow

I was wondering if anyone know how to make a dropped image shadow on the fly. When I get an input image I would like to have it displayed as the preview shows. Any tips or examples to get started in the right direction would be very appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the Reflection Effect, not Drop-Shadow, which is different.
You might want to refer to my article: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/image-processing-image-reflection-effect/

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to all of this and had no idea what it was called!